# When I have a spectrum analyzer, do I need a power analyzer?

Tags: antenna

I wonder whether I need a power analyzer or not in the case I already have a spectrum analyzer.

Do I need a power analyzer?

Application is antenna measurements.

Comment: To me, power analyzer means an instrument to measure things like 3-phase power and powerfactor. Is that the device you are referring to? Or some other kind of device?

Comment: @DKNguyen no, i mean RF output power

Comment: I think he's referring to a power meter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. A spectrum analyzer can do some things a power meter can but not everything.

Mainly it can't measure the *total* power in a given instant since it sweeps the frequency. Also a power meter is way more rugged and usually it has more power handling (there are two types of spectrum analyzer users: these who fried the input mixer and the ones which doesn't… yet).

If you do testing in CW in most cases a spectrum analyzer could do the job.

EDIT: usually a power meter is more accurate since it's an integrating device, but that's a finer point

EDIT: referring to power handling: a spectrum analyzer is designed to handle typically milliwatt level signal (remember, the input is terminated on 50 ohm so *everything* is dissipated on that terminator).

For high power you need an attenuator (colloquially called a 'bird' from a manufacturer name), or a power splitting network (and the associated complexity).

Since in the comment you're talking about 25W of power we are handling something like 45dBm of power with a spectrum analyzer you most likely overload it (often the max is 0dBm, the value is always printed over the input connector). 25W seems a lot but is actually one of the smaller power attenuators, you'll find them in the kW range too…

As an aside you'll probably need a VSWR bridge (reflection bridge) too, to test antennas in TX mode.

Comment: It's an antenna, so the power is CW. Do you think it will be enough with spectrum analyzer?

Comment: Well, it's not obvious that antennas work in CW. For most work it's enough if you don't need great precision. For lobe scanning, for example, it should be adequate

Comment: in both cases, i need power sensor, right?

Comment: No, with a spectrum analyzer you connect directly to the RF feed, maybe with an attenuator if you have a lot of power incoming. The power sensor is strictly the probe for the power meter, it doesn't have an RF output (in fact they use proprietary connectors)

Comment: One more question please, if we say the antenna has 25 W CW power handling, do I look over power sensor that has max output power 44 dBm like that?

Comment: Please don't post additional questions in the comments. Either amend your original question or raise a new question on the site.

Comment: A power analyser will be more accurate than a spectrum analyser. If you can tolerate a few dB power level inaccuracy, a spec ana is fine. You would use a power meter when you're producing or selling equipment that has to produce a warranted signal level, and that dB or two better power level accuracy translates into a specification advantage.